# What is the most efficient way to get information from excel using python and then paste to html table

Tags: python, excel

What is the most efficient way to get each 'AccountID: AB89561'  and its 'Category' with 'Price of' column value from the excel sheet that I can later paste in html table base on 'Price of' date and 'Category', for example I want get these information and then paste to html table :
[image]

then I would like to move to the another column of sheet 'Price of 10/2019' get values(prices) and paste values to corresponding category such as 'Delivery', Milk products', 'Drinks', 'Home appliances', 'Animals food' and paste values to the html table. Then move to another column 'Price of 11/2019' to get values(prices) and then paste to corresponding category such as ‘Delivery’... and so on, until all values 'Price of' columns will be pasted and then move to another below AccountID and continue.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For excel to python you can simply use pandas library in python that can read excel and you can then slice the data range that you want to select as final. Once you have the required data range in python, you can then use to_html() function to convert the same data range to html tables.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-render-pandas-dataframe-as-html-table/

this link should help you with the process.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution will be to read the xlsx file into memory using pandas. Then you can migrate it into a html table by using the to_html() function in the DataFrame.

For further information of how to use the function - follow : https://pythonexamples.org/pandas-render-dataframe-as-html-table/

For examples of reading an xlsx file - follow :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html